# JSF - Formattting <p:calendar> using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I have a `<p:calendar>` code in XHTML

```
<p:calendar
                                                value="#{Bean.targetdate}"
                                                pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" size="10" navigator="true"
                                                rendered="#{Bean.editCmdActionflg == true}"
                                                onblur="fChkDate(this);">
                                                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

My problem is when I provide a invalid date such as `12/31/6666` the `<p:calendar>` accept the date as it is and I did SOP in the backing bean and I got `Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 6666` for the date that I enter.

I should not allow the user to enter a invalid date like the one that I entered above. 
And I need to make sure the user should  provide a valid date
 How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use yearRange property to reslve your problem, like-

```
<p:calendar yearRange="c-125:c+50" value="#{Bean.targetdate}"  pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  readonlyInput="true" size="10" navigator="true"
                                            rendered="#{Bean.editCmdActionflg == true}"
                                            onblur="fChkDate(this);"/>
```

Comment: Also if you want to restrict the user to select date from desired range, you can use mindate and maxdate like- mindate="07/27/2010" maxdate="07/28/2012"

Comment: This is nothing just a way to declare the date range to avoid selecting invalid date range. c-125:c+50 will minus 125 years from current year and add 50 year in current year. So, this can define the year range. Hope this will help you as I understand the problem.